# PySpark: How to properly left join a copy of a table itself with multiple matching keys & resulting in duplicate column names?

Tags: python, join, pyspark, left-join

I have 1 dataframe that I would like to left join (join a copy of itself) in order to find next period's Value and Score:

DF has the following columns:

- Location
- Current_Period
- Next_Period
- Type
- Serial
- Category
- Value
- Score

I created a copy of DF by doing  `DF.select('*')`, then:

```
DF_copy = DF.select('*') 
DF_combine = DF.join(
                DF_copy, 
                (DF.Next_Period == DF_copy.Current_Period) &
                (DF.Location == DF_copy.Location) &
                (DF.Type == DF_copy.Type) &
                (DF.Serial == DF_copy.Serial) &
                (DF.Category == DF_copy.Category)
                )
```

I am not quite sure how to deal with the following issues:

1. There are going to be quite a few duplicate col names. How do I avoid running into error `"Found duplicate column(s)"` by adding a `'Next_Period'` string to "Value" and "Score" columns (i.e. "Next_Period_Value", "Next_Period_Score") once joined , while also drop other duplicates columns?
2. None of the columns listed are by itself a unique identifier, but when they are combined together, they become a unique identifier (which is why I need to use all the columns as join keys). Is this approach correct? Does the join order matters?

Very new to PySpark, much appreciation for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can select/modify the columns after a join using the `select` statement that you earlier used to create the `DF_copy`

#### Selecting the Columns

By only selecting and also modifying the column names , you can forgo the dropping of the other unnecessary columns from either of the join sources

```
DF_copy = DF.select('*') 
DF_combine = DF.join(
                DF_copy, 
                (DF.Next_Period == DF_copy.Current_Period) &
                (DF.Location == DF_copy.Location) &
                (DF.Type == DF_copy.Type) &
                (DF.Serial == DF_copy.Serial) &
                (DF.Category == DF_copy.Category)
               ).select(DF['*']
                       ,DF_copy['Value'].alias('Next_Period_Value')
                       ,DF_copy['Score'].alias('Next_Period_Score')
               )
```

Towards the joining keys , since you mentioned the combination makes a unique row , Hence it should not impact your overall objective , however you can quickly analyse to spot check if you see discrepancies. And lastly the order within the joining keys do not matter